# error when import zlib in iOS: symbol(s) not found collect2: ld

Tags: ios, linker, zlib

I have included `<zlib.h>` in my iphone application and the source code I was mocking up the sample code of Molecules provided by Brad Larson, however, when I build the project, it returns the error as below.  Can anyone point out for me whether this is a library linking problem or am I missing something else?

```
"_deflate", referenced from: -[NSData(Gzip) gzipDeflate] in NSData+Gzip.o "_inflateEnd", 
referenced from: -[NSData(Gzip) initWithGzippedData:] in NSData+Gzip.o "inflateInit2", 
referenced from: -[NSData(Gzip) initWithGzippedData:] in NSData+Gzip.o "_inflate", 
referenced from: -[NSData(Gzip) initWithGzippedData:] in NSData+Gzip.o "_deflateEnd", 
referenced from: -[NSData(Gzip) gzipDeflate] in NSData+Gzip.o "deflateInit2", referenced 
from: -[NSData(Gzip) gzipDeflate] in NSData+Gzip.o ld: symbol(s) not found collect2: ld 
returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Did you add libz to your project?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

In your Target's `Build Settings` tab, scroll down to the `Other Linker Flags` section and make sure `-lz` is in the field. This will link against the built-in zlib, and your error should go away.

After changing the Linker Flags you must select `Clean` from the `Product` menu before building again.

[image: lz screenshot]

Comment: I feel Jason's answer is a more reliable method.

Comment: @Plumenator In Ben's answer you are using a libz that is ALREADY part of your app. In Jason's answer you are adding an additional libz to the application. That's why Ben's answer is better, it's more efficient (no offense to Jason of course).

Answer (score 46):

Add libz to your project. To do this, follow these steps in Xcode:

1. Open your project, select your project target and then click the blue project info icon on your toolbar (or press ⌘I)
   [image: Example 1]
2. Click the + button in the lower-left corner of the screen to add a library, scroll down to the bottom of the library list and select libz.dylib; click the Add button.
   [image: Example 2]
3. Once you've clicked add, you will see that the library name appears in oyur list of Linked Libraries. You will now be able to build your project without linking errors.
   [image: Example 3]

You can use this same method to add any library from the list. If the library does not appear on the list, then you know that it is not part of the standard iPhone SDK and you may need to rethink your solution or build the library statically yourself and link your target to that (if even possible).

Comment: -1 – while it's a very nice answer, libz.dylib is no-longer available when you add a library to your target and they shouldn't be used anyway for standard libraries. Instead add `-lz` to your linker flags.