# Setting up lib haru in an iPhone project for pdf creation

Tags: iphone, pdf, libharu

Has anyone ever setup lib haru on the iPhone and can tell me how to get it to work. I know there is a sample project on github (http://github.com/akisute/iPhonePDF) which uses the haru lib for creating a pdf. But I just can not figure out how to get the library to work.

What I did so far:

- First I copied the support folder of the sample project on github
- I added the two static libraries haru and png.
- Then I added the linked libraries for both.
- I also added the framework libz

When I try building it, I get the error can not find library -lharu

Do I need to install it first, I really do not have any clue?
I never tried to include a C Library into my iPhone project before.

Thanks a lot for any kind of hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just installed it in XCode 4:

- In the iPhonePDF's folder downloaded from http://github.com/akisute/iPhonePDF you have a support folder with the libharu and the libpng folders inside. The trick here is the files you copy to your project. Delete the script files and, specially, the file named `pngtest.c` from the libpng folder.
- Once you have the folders "clean", you can add them to your project and it will compile.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this? //Delete the script files//
Also can you share if we have to set any paths in project settings?
Can you share your folder structure?

Thanks in advance

Comment: With script files I refer to `Makefile.am` and `Makefile.in`. If you don't remove them you'll have a huge crack when compiling. I only had to copy the libpng and libharu folders (after deleting that Makefiles) to my project (drag & drop the folders for example in a "PDFGeneration" group inside your project in XCode. And then compile and it should work!

Comment: You may also need to add the -lz flag to the "Other Linker Flags" on your target.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/289294/416622

Comment: @Ruben Esposito: I am not finding any make files in libpng and libharu folders .Its giving me many compiler errors

Comment: can any one tell me ,is it possible to convert html to pdf using libharu ?

Comment: Does libharu generate the pdf in Japanese language by default ? How to translate it to English ?