# How to use bzip2 format in iOS? Apple tell me bzBuffToBuffDecompress is private APIs

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, app-store, iphone-privateapi, bzip2

Today I submit my iOS App to app store, but soon I got a mail from apple, it said that,

> cannot be posted to the App Store
>   because it is using private or
>   undocumented APIs:
>
> ```
> Private Symbol References
>
> BZ2_bzBuffToBuffDecompress
> ```
>
> As you know, as outlined in the iPhone
>   Developer Program License Agreement
>   section 3.3.1, the use of non-public
>   APIs is not permitted. Before your
>   application can be reviewed by the App
>   Review Team, please resolve this issue
>   and upload a new binary to iTunes
>   Connect.

What should I do? I realy need bzip2 format support in my app.

Comment: WTF ? The use of SQLite is OK but bzip2 is not ?

Comment: Even more bizarre, I completely forgot that they allow the use zlib... prohibiting bzip2 looks more like an oversight to me now simply because they haven't added the docs in the SDK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the license of bzip2 is compatible (read it, please) you can statically link against bzip2 instead of dynamically. A bit of searching lead to [iOS-libarchive](https://github.com/davepeck/iOS-libarchive) that will help you do that.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to statically link against bzip2 to see what happended.

Comment: I add static bzip2 to my project, but Xcode still using dynamical version, so I change libbz2.a to libzz2.a, Xcode can not find dynamical version, so it works.

Answer (score 4):

From Ben Gottlieb's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289274/error-when-import-zlib-in-iphone-sdk):

> In your Target settings window, scroll
>   down to the "Other Linker Flags"
>   section and make sure that -lz is in
>   the field. This will link against the
>   built-in zlib, and your error should
>   go away.

Except in this case, you want to use the -lbz2 flag.