# Compress NSString in Cocoa and uncompress in PHP

Tags: php, cocoa, nsstring, compression, bzip2

I would like to send large NSStrings from Cocoa to PHP.

Can I use the bzlib library to compress these strings on the fly (therefore to compress in memory, not from disk), and then to be able to uncompress them in PHP ?

If yes, any reference code/function available ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to send NSString objects from Cocoa to PHP. I'm guessing that you just want to send the payload strings within the objects from a Cocoa app up to a PHP script on a server and compress the string in transit in order to minimize network bandwidth. A laudable goal.

On the Cocoa side, use the [bzip2 library and associated programming manual](http://www.bzip.org/1.0.3/bzip2-manual-1.0.3.html) to implement compression. The good news here is that you should be able to do the compression entirely in memory using BZ2_bzCompressInit, BZ2_bzCompress, and BZ2_bzCompressEnd. Also, you mentioned Cocoa vs. Cocoa Touch, but if you're planning to submit this to the App Store, [heed this post's advice and statically link the bzip2 library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124298/how-to-use-bzip2-format-in-ios-apple-tell-me-bzbufftobuffdecompress-is-private).

On the PHP side, [follow this documentation to decompress the file](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bzip2.php). The downside here is that it's apparently necessary to save the bzip2 string to a temporary file before decompressing it.