# ziparchive Objective-C arc compatible

Tags: objective-c, ios5, automatic-ref-counting, php-ziparchive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [error when import zlib in iOS: symbol(s) not found collect2: ld](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289274/error-when-import-zlib-in-iphone-sdk)

I am working on iphone project and I need a library to extract ZIP file
I found ZipArchive but it doesn't compatible with ARC and when I add -fno-objc-arc to compile files I get linker error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
>         _unzCloseCurrentFile in unzip.o
>     "*inflateInit2*", referenced from:
>         _unzOpenCurrentFile3 in unzip.o
>     "_get_crc_table", referenced from:
>         _unzOpenCurrentFile3 in unzip.o
>         _zipOpenNewFileInZip3 in zip.o
>     "_crc32", referenced from:
>         _unzReadCurrentFile in unzip.o
>         _zipWriteInFileInZip in zip.o
>         -[ZipArchive addFileToZip:newname:] in ZipArchive.o
>     "_inflate", referenced from:
>         _unzReadCurrentFile in unzip.o
>     "*deflateInit2*", referenced from:
>         _zipOpenNewFileInZip3 in zip.o
>     "_deflate", referenced from:
>         _zipWriteInFileInZip in zip.o
>         _zipCloseFileInZipRaw in zip.o
>     "_deflateEnd", referenced from:
>         _zipCloseFileInZipRaw in zip.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the undefined symbols, you need to add libz to the linked libraries.  See: [error when import zlib in iphone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289274/error-when-import-zlib-in-iphone-sdk)